SpringBoot test / How to apply environment variables binding to YAML?
I have a Spring Boot based application with a class whose fields are populated via @ConfigurationProperties. One of the fields is a list of strings:
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "company")
public class Company {

    private List<String> employeeNameList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Getters etc. omitted for brevity

}

To assign values to this list, I can write in the YAML configuration:
company.employeeNameList:
  - Emp1
  - Emp2

The same list can be populated via environment variables using Binding From Environment Variables by setting the environment variables as follows:
company_employeeNameList_0 = Emp1
company_employeeNameList_1 = Emp2

My question is: How can I use the environment variables names in the YAML config? I.e. I'd like to have the YAML config like this (exactly the same names and syntax of the entries as in the env vars):
company_employeeNameList_0: Emp1
company_employeeNameList_1: Emp2

The reason why I want to do this is this. We run the application and customize it by setting some env vars (the defs are in a file). Now I want to write a test that verifies whether the vars have been specified correctly. To this purpose, I'd like to copy the env vars definitions from the file to a spring YAML config and let SpringBoot use that config.
But SpringBoot seems to apply the binding only to env vars, not to YAML configs. I.e. if I use the YAML config
company_employeeNameList_0: Emp1
company_employeeNameList_1: Emp2

the list does NOT get populated with two values.
This syntax works:
company.employeeNameList[0]: Emp1
company.employeeNameList[1]: Emp2

But I'd like to use exactly the same names as they are used in the env vars, i.e. with underscores and without brackets.

May be this video from Dan Vega will helps you.

Try export environment variable like this (in linux system):
export company_employeeNameList=Emp1,Emp2


This was just an example, the real values are more complex. My goal is to use them in a spring boot test exactly as they are specified in the script for the runtime environment setup.
